# there’s no pygame in Colab?

Tags: python, pygame

I saw some Python fractal rendering code and I wanted to try it inside Colab. I copied the code, made a new file, and copied it in and... it didn’t work. I wondered why, and it said “Module not found”.
The import code looked like this:

```
import pygame, sys, math, random, os
import numpy as np
import pyspace
```

This is what I think triggered the error itself:

```
import pygame
```

Like I said, I did this in Colab. Unless I figure out how to fix this myself, you need to figure out how to do this.

Comment: *"you need to figure out how to do this"*. Actually, no I don't. I couldn't give a monkeys.

Comment: You shouldn't need to think what triggered the error, the stack trace should tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not there, you just need to install it.

```
!pip install pygame
```